# Invoke a python script on ubuntu on each google search

Tags: python, linux, networking

I am trying to make a custom website blocker in python. I would run it as a service in my ubuntu 18.04 system. Now what I want to achieve is that whenever a user searches something on google( or whatever link I visit), that script is invoked and if the requested website is in the block list, the script would just terminate the request. so how would I capture the network request that would be made from my browser in my python script?

Is it possible to capture the network requests in a log file in linux?

Comment: You can capture the query using `tcpdump`

Comment: You can block very easily a lot of web site using `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Yes I know it using ``/etc/hosts`` but I want to customize it. That is, 9-5 it should block, otherwise the website should be able to run. Thats why I am making a custom blocker.

Comment: Actually what I am trying to achieve is that whenever any network request passes through an interface, my python script should catch it and handle it.

Comment: In that case, you might want to create a proxy. You could look at https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/writing-http-proxy-in-python-with-mitmproxy

Comment: How can I use this to fulfill my purpose? Can you please explain a little?